# print statement if no condition is met in bash

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have a bash script that determines if someone's aws keys are older than 90 days. If they are the script sends them an email with info on how to rotate they keys.

I want the script to print a statement if NO keys are older than 90 days, so an email does not get sent.

I have two if independent if statements for each user's key:

```
if [ "$key1dtSec" -lt "$taSec" ]; then
    printf "%s created on %s\\nThis key is %s days old and needs to be replaced.\\nAn email will be sent." "$user_access_key1" "$key1_date_created." "$key1AgeDays"
    echo -e  "$template1" | /usr/bin/mail --append="Content-type: text/html" -s "AWS Key Rotation Needed for $user_name in $aws_key" "$email_address"
    echo; echo
fi

if [ "$key2dtSec" -lt "$taSec" ]; then
    printf "%s created on %s.\\nThis key is %s days old and needs to be replaced.\\nAn email will be sent." "$user_access_key2" "$key2_date_created"  "$key2AgeDays"
    echo -e  "$template2" | /usr/bin/mail --append="Content-type: text/html" -s "AWS Key Rotation Needed for $user_name in $aws_key" "$email_address"
    echo; echo
fi
```

`key1dtSec` and `key2dtSec` is the age of the aws key in seconds. `taSec` is set to 90 days ago.

If I use an `elif` statement and use only one if/then statement for both keys, then only the first if statement that tells if a key is older than 90 days gets executed.

How can I write this so that:

1. If the first key is older than 90 days and email is sent.
2. If the second key is older than 90 days an email is sent.
3. If no key is older than 90 days a message is printed that says no key is older than 90 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your logic is like:

```
if condition1; then # first key
  action1 # send email
fi

if condition2; then # second key
  action2 # send different email
fi

if ! condition1 && ! condition2; then # neither key
  action3 # print something
fi
```

If so, replace `condition1` with `[ "$key1dtSec" -lt "$taSec" ]`, same for `condition2`, and insert the appropriate actions in each block.

Answer (score 2):

Hoping, I understood your question correctly. Please check below answer.

```
    key1=0
    key2=0

    if [ "$key1dtSec" -lt "$taSec" ]; then
        printf "%s created on %s\\nThis key is %s days old and needs to be replaced.\\nAn email will be sent." "$user_access_key1" "$key1_date_created." "$key1AgeDays"
        echo -e  "$template1" | /usr/bin/mail --append="Content-type: text/html" -s "AWS Key Rotation Needed for $user_name in $aws_key" "$email_address"
        echo; echo
        key1=1
       fi

     if [ "$key2dtSec" -lt "$taSec" ]; then
            printf "%s created on %s.\\nThis key is %s days old and needs to be replaced.\\nAn email will be sent." "$user_access_key2" "$key2_date_created"  "$key2AgeDays"
        echo -e  "$template2" | /usr/bin/mail --append="Content-type: text/html" -s "AWS Key Rotation Needed for $user_name in $aws_key" "$email_address"
        echo; echo
        key2=1
       fi

     if [  "$key1" -eq 0 && "$key2" -eq 0]; then 
        echo "no key is older than 90 days."
        fi
```

Comment: `-eq 0]` at the end is a syntax error, and this creates two additional global variables where one (or zero, as in my answer) would suffice.

Comment: @Tom Fenech ues, Thanks for the suggestion. Pardon syntax error